# SAS connect to SQL Server dsn less

Tags: sas

I am trying to setup a DSN less connection to SQL Server on a SAS unix machine following this example:

http://support.sas.com/kb/52/777.html

```
libname mylib odbc noprompt="driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;
                             server=server-name;
                             uid=user-ID;
                             pwd=password; 
                             database=SQL-database"
                   schema=schema-name;
```

But I got:

> ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] ODBCINST.INI is not available in the directory pointed to by the ODBCINST environment variable (or the current user's HOME directory) and therefore DSN-Less connections cannot be made.

Comment: According to the [DataDirect docs](https://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/index.html#page/odbc/dsn-less-connections.html), "Setup installs a default version of this file in the product installation directory", and judging from the error message, you have to point the ODBCINST environment variable to the directory the file is in, or copy/link it to the current user's HOME directory.